# If $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ converges, does there exist $0<c<1$ such that for $c \le p \le 1,$ $\int_a^\infty f^p(x)$ converges?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> True Or False: If $f(x)$ is a positive continuous function in $[a,\infty)$ such that $\int_a^\infty f(x)\;dx$ converges then exists $ 0 < c < 1$ such that for every $c \le p \le 1$ $\int_a^\infty f^p(x)\;dx$ converges.

It feels true to me since the function will remain continuous after being raised to a power and all powers are less then 1 so it should not make the value too big.But I'm not sure I'm on the right track, and can't see how to prove it.

Comment: Consider the function $\frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}$ for $x>1$.

Comment: As a counter example for a partly inversed question: With $f(x) = \frac 1 x $, $\int_{1}^\infty f(x) dx = \infty$, but for all $p>1$ we have $$\int_{1}^\infty f^p(x) dx < \infty$$ So an ever so small local change in value might still make a big difference

Comment: @Sudix Yea, I was trying to get something like that to work for me, but always found a $c$ large enough so that $f^c$ ended up with $p>1$ The trick was to introduce a $log$ into the mix I suppose. There are probably other examples too. (besides the construction method mentioned below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}$ for $x\in[a,\infty)$ for $a>1$.

Comment: Nice example! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jason!  You're welcome. It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly good to become acquainted with $\log$-type examples, such as the one Mark Viola mentions. But I sometimes like to build these things up from the ground.

Sketch of a counterexample: For $x\ge 1,$ define

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^nx^{1+1/n}}.$$

The series converges unifomly on $[1,\infty),$ hence $f$ is continuous, and $\int_1^\infty f < \infty.$

Claim: $\int_1^\infty f^p=\infty$ for every $p\in (0,1).$

Proof: Suppose $0<p<1.$ Choose $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $p(1+1/n_0) < 1.$ Then

$$\int_1^\infty f^p \ge \int_1^\infty \left (\frac{1}{2^{n_0}x^{1+1/n_0}}\right)^p\,dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n_0p}x^{p(1+1/n_0)}}\,dx = \infty.$$

Comment: (+1) Nice example and thank you for the homage, but I'm not sure as to how "to build [this] up from the ground."

Comment: @MarkViola It's like building a cabin without logs.

Comment: So, you're without logs and building a cabin, or you're trying to build a cabin-without-logs?  Or was that a pun and play on words (logs = logarithms)?  In that case, you ought to go to the punitentiary.

Comment: Cool method of building up a function which works! It's shorter to find and example like @MarkViola but it's nice to see another way of solving this!